# New driveway concrete

Tags: concrete

I had a concrete driveway poured approximately 10 months ago the stains never came out of it dark gray stains throughout of it how can I stain  this smooth finish concrete driveway to make it look better

Comment: "The stains never came out of it..." What stains are you referring to?

Comment: If you want some diferent color acid coloring works. Sounds like an inconsistent mix or different truck loads.

Comment: Stack Exchange loves photos... got some?

Answer (score 1):

If this was done by a licensed contractor it should be all one color.call and ask if they know why and if they will fix it. the next step would be to call the state contractor's board. no matter what color of stain you use it will have dark areas.depending on the variegations between light and dark it could look very good if the right color is used. an epoxy paint might cover it if heavy enough.the main issue is if the concrete was mixed properly.If it was not it could deteriorate far before its life expectancy is reached.